# Как проследить, менялись ли данные внутри 'динамического' массива?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Добрый день.
Никак не могу продумать такую вещь:
Имеется массив, с 2 элементами. Допустим это диапозон возраста, который указывает пользователь. Знаете, есть такие слайдеры, устанавливающие диапозон, [вот как этот](http://www.xiper.net/examples/js-plugins/ui/ui-slider/). Т.е. массив имеет 2 значения, например 18 и 25. (лет)

```
mas=[18,25]
```

И как только пользователь вводит этот диапозон, выполняется аякс запрос. Причем аякс запрос выполняется КАЖДЫЙ раз, когда пользователь нажмет на "слайдер выбора диапозона", даже если он не менял значения а просто прикоснулся к одному из ползунков. Мне же нужно какимто образом проверять, изменил он значения этих ползунков или же просто притронулся (сфокусировался на нём).
Понятно что нужно массив сверять... И будь массив статичный проблем бы не было, а так я никак не могу уловить - относительно чего же нужно сверять его? Ведь пользователь может сначала изменить значения (напр. [18,36]), потом просто притронутся к ползунку (притронутся - я имею ввиду совершить onclick на ползунке), но ничего не менять..
Есть у кого-то какие-то идеи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть значение до клика, и есть значение после клика, берем и сверяем их, в чем проблема?

Comment: та меня подталкивать пока что нужно, даже если что-то очевидное)
спасибо) за минуту разобрался)))